# Exporting modules in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript1.8

I'm new to typescript, I'm working with Node.js 5.10.1 and tsc 1.8.9.
I'm trying to create a simple ts file that contains a function that I can use.

Since I'm using external modules and since my app is Node.js based I'm using the typescript-require 3rd library module.

This is my `my-util.ts` file:

```js
"use strict";

var fs = require('fs');

export module MyUtil {
    export function isFileReadable(filePath:string, callback:Function) {
        fs.access(filePath, fs.R_OK, (err) => {
            callback(err, null);
        });
    }
}
```

Now... in the main `ts` file which is currently.. empty. I want to require 
the `my-util.ts` file and use the function `isFileReadable`.

What I correct to add export to the module `MyUtil`? How do I require it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend exporting it as a class with static methods.  modules are more geared for the .d.ts files now.  They used to be for modules in general before the es2015 specification landed.  The following answers assume you are compiling all of your TypeScript code properly.

Try this instead:

```
"use strict";
var fs = require('fs');

export class MyUtil {
    static isFileReadable(filePath:string, callback:Function) {
        fs.access(filePath, fs.R_OK, (err) => {
            callback(err, null);
        });
    }
}
```

Then to use it (using standard node imports) you would do:

```
var util = require('./my-util').MyUtil;
util.isFileReadble(...)
```

Using ES6 imports you would do:

```
import {MyUtil} from './my-util';
MyUtil.isFileReadble(...)
```